# How to prototype extend the document object in IE9?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I want to override the native `document.write` function so I'm doing this:

```
HTMLDocument.prototype.write = function(arg) {
    alert('Do Something!');
};
```

This works in every browser except IE9 where it throws the following error:

`'HTMLDocument' is undefined`

It even works in IE 8. How to extend the document object in IE9?

Comment: why don't you just assign to `document.write`? are you manipulating lots of different documents?

Comment: If I recall correctly then IE 9 should support `HTMLDocument` so this message indicates that IE is compatibility mode and not in standard mode.

Comment: You could try changing the document mode using a metatag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

Comment: Why are you doing this? It's [*not a good strategy*](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, somewhere before IE 9 was about to be published `HTMLDocument` was replaced with `Document` and it was like this in IE 10 as well. However, in IE 11 both objects are back and following returns *true*:

```
Document.prototype.write === HTMLDocument.prototype.write
```

even though Document and HTMLDocument reference different objects. So to do what you want for IE 9 and IE 10 (I didn't check IE 8 behavior) you could do something like:

```
Document.prototype.write = function(arg) {
    alert('Do Something!');
};
```

Comment: ended up doing `var document_extend = typeof HTMLDocument !== 'undefined' ? HTMLDocument : Document;` then `document_extend.prototype.write = function(arg)...`